# R Shiny: "Reactive" data analysis based on user input, followed by ggplot figure output

Tags: r, user-interface, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

I have a basic R code where, within the code, a user can enter a country name "Argentina". Using that value/name, the code will run an analysis for the "Argentina" subset of the pre-loaded data. Finally, the code will produce a simple ggplot showing results.

I have tried to make this code into a Shiny App, however I cannot get it to work properly. My main issue is that I cannot seem to get the data analysis in the Server section to work, which should subsequently feed into the plotting code. More importantly, I cannot seem to get the user inputted country name to feed into my data analysis.

Without going into the detail of the code, could someone kindly point me in the right direction of how one would do this in Shiny? e.g.

1. Field for user input;
2. Use that user input as an object used in the code;
3. subsequently run the analysis (whatever it might be); and
4. use the final analysis data frame in ggplot for a figure output to be displayed in the shiny app.

Please see my shiny code currently used, with reproducible data using MTcars

```
library(shiny)

# Some Sample data to run app using mtcars
mtcars$Primary<- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$Area <- "Argentina"
mtcars$Y2016<- mtcars$mpg
mtcars$Element <- "Gross Production Value (constant 2004-2006 million US$)"

# Defining UI ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

          # App title ----
          headerPanel("Subsector Selection Tool"),

          # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
          sidebarPanel(

            # Input: Country name
            textInput("country", "Please enter country name", "")#,
          ),

          # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
          mainPanel("")
)


# Define server logic to plot various variables against mpg ----
server <- function(input, output) {

 #Trying to make user inputed country name into an object to be used in 
 "reactive" code below, which in turn is be used to make dataset for graphing
 country_interest <- reactive({
 paste(input$country)
 })


#Here I am trying to make the data analysis code run and create desired 
dataset for graphing, and subsetting for country selected by user
Value_c_e_PRIM_x  <- reactive({

Value_c <- Value[which(Value$Area==country_interest),]
Value_c_e <- Value_c[which(Value_c$Element=="Gross Production Value (constant 2004-2006 million US$)"),]
Value_c_e_PRIM$Primary <- Value_c_e_PRIM[,120]
Value_c_e_PRIM[,120] <- NULL

Value_c_e_PRIM <-  Value_c_e_PRIM %>% group_by(Primary,Element) %>% summarise_at(vars(Y2016), sum)

Value_c_e_PRIM$Category <- "Value of Production"
Value_c_e_PRIM$Value <- Value_c_e_PRIM$Y2016
Value_c_e_PRIM <-  Value_c_e_PRIM %>% group_by(Category,Primary) %>% summarise_at(vars(Value), mean)

})


#Graphing section, if  Ihave the dataset "Value_c_e_PRIM_x" pre-loaded (e.g. not derived in code above), the figure is successfully shown in the output.
output$plot <- renderPlot({

Graph_data <- Value_c_e_PRIM_x 
Graph_data$Score_type <- "Competitiveness Score"
Graph_data$`Competitiveness Score` <- round(Graph_data$Value, 2)

title1 <-paste("Competitiveness\nby",paste0(country_interest),"Subsector")
mycol <-c("red", "yellow", "#006600")

ggplot(data = Graph_data, aes(x = Score_type, y = reorder(Primary,Value), fill=Value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Value), colour= "white")+
  geom_text(data=Graph_data,aes(y=Primary, x= Score_type, label=Value))+
  labs(title =(paste0(title1)),y = "", x = "")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = mycol)+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When getting the value from reactive elements, be sure to use parenthsis -- they are more like functions than values. So `Value$Area==country_interest()` and `Graph_data <- Value_c_e_PRIM_x()`. Since you seem to be new to shiny i strongly recommend you check out [Joe Cheng's presentations on Reactivity](https://resources.rstudio.com/shiny-developer-conference) to get started.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. By any chance, would you know why only me text entry box appears in the app when I run the code (even if your suggestions)? If I remove the text entry for something else (like TRUE/FALSE selection option) - my ggplot figure works, as long as my data for the plot is pre-loaded. The "reactive" data analysis section is seemingly still not working.